# Declaring global, static variables

Tags: vb.net, static, global-variables

I'm trying to set a global variable in Visual Studio, but I can't make it static. Is there any way for me to set the variable as static and share it across different methods, or some way to save the variable each time it changes?

Comment: Static in VB.NET is `Shared`. Call it in this way: `ClassName.SharedVariableName`. It must be `Public` to be accessible from outside of this class. Note that you are not sharing it only across methods but also across different threads which can cause locks or incorrect results (f.e. in ASP.NET).

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance on "Shared" being static. It appears that I am either facing a run-time error in my work, or are using the "Shared" form of variable . Would you please give me an example?

Comment: Can you post your code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options:

1 - Create a class that contains a Shared variable (this is the same as a static variable in C#)

```
    Public Class GlobalVariables
        Public Shared Bar As String
    End Class
```

You can then access this using the class name:

```
GlobalVariables.Bar = "Hello world"
```

2 - Create a module (this is akin to a static class in C#)

```
    Public Module GlobalVariables
        Public Bar As String
    End Module
```

You can then access this value in code like this:

```
Bar = "Goodbye cruel world"
```

Comment: What I did was put the Shared variable inside the same class as the methods used, and referred to it as the variable name without the classname. in classname.variablename because it was inside the same class. Could this be the error? Also, do I put a meth od like you would find a button click function (for example)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the number 1 option presented by @Matt Wilko, you can reference the shared member either through an object instance of the class or by referencing the class without an object reference. Both point to and increment the same variable and therefore reference the same value. Although, the Visual Studio compiler provides a warning about referencing an object instance and says that it will not be evaluated, it still compiles. The compiler's recommendation is to use the class name.

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared Foo As Integer
End Class
```

Insert the following into a form and call IncrementIntegers() from a button click event procedure and you will find that myGlobalVariables.Foo and GlobalVariables.Foo both return 20.

```
Private Sub IncrementIntegers()
   Dim myGlobalVariables As New GlobalVariables
   myGlobalVariables.Foo = 0
   GlobalVariables.Foo = 0
   myGlobalVariables.Foo += 10
   GlobalVariables.Foo += 10
   Dim iLocalInt1 = myGlobalVariables.Foo 
   MessageBox.Show("myGlobalVariables.Foo = " & iLocalInt1.ToString)
   Dim iLocalInt2 = GlobalVariables.Foo 
   MessageBox.Show("GlobalVariables.Foo = " & iLocalInt2.ToString)
End Sub
```

Note that with option 1, Foo must be qualified with either the class name or an object name. With option 2, it is a module and not a class so an object reference cannot be created. The public variable can be referenced without qualifying it with the module name unless a variable with the same name appears in another module in which case the compiler with throw a name conflict error. For example,

```
Public Module1

   Public Foo As String

End Module

Public Module2

   Public Foo As String

End Module
```

Remove Module2 and Foo can be called unqualified from anywhere.

```
Foo = "Happy birthday"
```

With Module2 present, Foo must be qualified with the name as both point to different variable and represent different and independent values.

```
Module1.Foo = "Goodbye cruel world"
Module2.Foo = "Hello new world"
```

Comment: This has been answered and solved, thanks everybody.