# Variable not updating in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem getting a global variable to update in VB.NET. The declared value is 0, but the variable changes according to a choice that the user makes.

I have multiple forms, and I have tried updating the variable on 2 different forms with the same result.

I declared the variable like so:

```
Public Shared creativity As Integer = 0
Public Shared comboBox = frmStart.cbxCombo.SelectedItem
```

To change the value I used:

```
If comboBox = "Yes" Then
    creativity += 30
End If
```

I expect the value of creativity to be 30, but it is still showing as 0. I have even tried:

```
creativity = creativity + 30
```

but I am still getting the same result, with the value displaying as 0.

Comment: Woudl this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384296/declaring-global-static-variables

Comment: How certain are you that the line `creativity += 30` is being run?

Comment: @Renat I actually do have the variables declared in a separate class, I just failed to include it within my code. I named the class VarClass, and for each instance I would call VarClass.creativity or VarClass.comboBox

Comment: @JayV when I test the program, I set the selected item of the combo box to "Yes" for testing purposes

Comment: Changing the value of a variable like that will not automatically update a control in another form.  Only the debugger can show you the value.  Consider an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the function being called in the code?

For something like

```
public sub comboBox_change()
    If comboBox = "Yes" Then
        creativity += 30
    End If
End sub
```

The function call will occur whenever the combo box is change, which you could end up with a stacking issue (multiple calls of the same function, all increment it each time it is changed).

If you have it in a function that is not called, then of course it is not being incremented, as the code is never executed, like if you made a

```
public sub ThisIsMyCode()
    ...
End sub
```

Without a call reference.

Comment: that may actually work. The combo box will only be displayed once, so stacking shouldn't occur. I'm going to change and test my code with this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Cryostasys! I was still having a problem at first, but then I found it. I was calling the event as a Private Sub instead of Public. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should put this code

```
If comboBox = "Yes" Then
    creativity += 30
End If
```

inside the `SelectedItemChanged` event of your combobox

Also, you should put this:

```
Public Shared comboBox = frmStart.cbxCombo.SelectedValue
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the combo box is located on a different form than where the output should be displayed and updated